# Using JWT in Laravel 5.1 for user's authentication

Tags: session, laravel, cookies, csrf, jwt

I'm setting up a Laravel website, and I'm struggling with **user identification**.

I'd like to use `JWT` (JSON Web Tokens) in the `Cookie`. But AFAIK Cookies are MITM and CSRF vulnerable, which I want to avoid.

On the other hand, using `Local Storage` seems to be XSS vulnerable.

Given the platform I'm using, is there a reasonable way to have user identification with as little security issues as possible?

Comment: JWT already had some encryption and message verification built into it, and Laravel allows you to encrypt the cookie itself as well, so MITM won't cause any information to be revealed. The only thing you have to worry about is the MITMer getting hold of the cookie and reusing it exactly as-is. The solution for this is to tie the user's session to a single IP address, and to require frequent session renewal. Also, make sure you have properly set up HTTPS-only access. As far as CSRF protection, that should be done using built-in CSRF tokens which are entirely unrelated to your login mechanism.

Comment: The problem with the CSRF protection in Laravel 5.1 is that the framework needs to keep the Laravel's Session Cookie to create the X-SRF token Cookie. 
So I end with the Laravel's default Cookies, the one I add (with the JWT) and I'm still **working with sessions**...That's why I don't see the point of using JWT instead of Laravel's default Session authentication.